# Check if android drawable exists in ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, drawable

I've tried to implement this using an example found on a stackoverflow answer:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable","your.package.namespace");
if (resId == 0){
Log.v("DRAWABLE", "not found");
} else {
//getDrawable like this
Log.v("DRAWABLE", "found");
}
```

However this does not address the case where this is executed in an ASyncTask. I've even passed an instance of the activity calling the task:

```
callingActivity.getResources().getIdentifier("icon",.... but that also doesn't work
```

EDIT: Sorry I've added the full code snippet. In each case I attempt to log the outcome and although some drawables exist, all results output not found.

Comment: Describe "doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry just edited my answer to include further detail

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int check = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()); 
if ( check != 0 ) {
 // the resouce exists... 
result = true; 
} else { 
// the resouce does NOT exist
 result = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, in the "icon" parameter i was passing in the filename of the image with the extension e.g. image.jpg, where I should have passed without the extension. Once i removed this it was able to find the drawable.